# How to convert flat list to nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to know how to convert a  flat list to a nested dictionary.

For example,

`[1, 2, 3, 4]` to `{1: {2: {3: 4}}}`

I tried:

```
nested_list = {i[1]:{{i[x]:i[x+1]} for x in range(2,len(i - 1))}}
```

in which `i` is the list.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `functools.reduce(lambda x, y: {y: x}, reversed(i))`

Comment: Is that a real world problem, or an interview question?

Comment: btw, `i` is usually the name of an index (as in `for i in range(...)`). I would recommend to not use it as a "normal" variable name

Answer (score 5):

This process is actually a [right fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#On_lists) (I realized this when learning Haskell). If we have a right folding function `foldr` that does not require an initial value, we can implement it according to the following code:

```
def make_nested_dict(iterable):
    return foldr(lambda x, y: {x: y}, iterable)
```

Unfortunately, there is no such thing in the stdlib. A simple implementation is to use `functools.reduce`, which is essentially a left fold. The third duality theorem (you can refer to [here](https://www.cantab.net/users/antoni.diller/haskell/units/unit06.html)) states:

```
# There is no need to consider the initial value here
def foldr(func, lst):
    return foldl(lambda x, y: func(y, x), reversed(lst))
```

Therefore, we can obtain a concise implementation as follows:

```
from functools import reduce


def make_nested_dict(iterable):
    try:
        it = reversed(iterable)
    except TypeError:
        it = reversed(tuple(iterable))

    return reduce(lambda y, x: {x: y}, it)
```

Test:

```
>>> make_nested_dict(range(10))
{0: {1: {2: {3: {4: {5: {6: {7: {8: 9}}}}}}}}}
>>> make_nested_dict(iter(range(10)))
{0: {1: {2: {3: {4: {5: {6: {7: {8: 9}}}}}}}}}
```

One limitation is that for an iterative object with a length less than 2, the results it gives may not be satisfactory:

```
>>> make_nested_dict(range(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in make_nested_dict
TypeError: reduce() of empty iterable with no initial value
>>> make_nested_dict(range(1))
0
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a generic solution:

```
def make_dict(ll):
    if len(ll) < 2:
        return {}
    dd = {ll[-2]: ll[-1]}
    for i in range(3, len(ll) + 1):
        dd = {ll[-i]: dd}
    return dd


print(make_dict([1, 2, 3, 4]))

print(make_dict([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))

print(make_dict([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

Result:

```
{1: {2: {3: 4}}}
{1: {2: {3: {4: 5}}}}
{1: {2: {3: {4: {5: {6: {7: {8: 9}}}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursive option

```
def make_dict(x):
    def rmd(a):
        if len(a) == 2:
            return {a[0]: a[1]}
        return {a[0]: rmd(a[1:])}

    if len(x) < 2:
        return None
    if len(x) == 2:
        return {x[0]: x[1]}
    return {x[0]: rmd(x[1:])}

for i in range(5):
    lst = list(range(i))
    print(f'{lst} >> {make_dict(lst)}')
```

Output:

```
[] >> None
[0] >> None
[0, 1] >> {0: 1}
[0, 1, 2] >> {0: {1: 2}}
[0, 1, 2, 3] >> {0: {1: {2: 3}}}
```